# Getting directory of file

Tags: bash, init, monit

I have found an error in `monit` init script that I want to fix on my own for now. The faulty code is

```
PID_DIR=$(/bin/basename "$MONIT_PID_FILE")
/bin/mkdir -p -m0700 "$PID_DIR"
```

The developer wants to create the directory `/var/run/monit` from `$MONIT_PID_FILE` that equals to `/var/run/monit/monit.pid`, but unfortunately basename returns the file name, not directory path. This causes the directory not being created and monit not starting.

How can I get a file's directory full path starting from the file's full path? ie. `/usr/local/myfile.f` => `/usr/local`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dirname` to get the directory path (instead of using `basename`).

Refer: [dirname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirname)